# Weird ambiguity for class func() in inherited classes [Swift]

Tags: swift, inheritance, swift5

I have a simple class hierarchy like this in Swift.

```
class Parent {
    var name:String = "Unnamed"
    class func all() -> [Parent] {
        return Dad.all() + Mom.all()
    }
}

class Dad:Parent {
    static var AllDads:[Dad] = []

    class func all() -> [Dad] {
        return AllDads
    }
}

class Mom:Parent {
    static var AllMoms:[Mom] = []

    class func all() -> [Mom] {
        return AllMoms
    }
}

Mom.all().forEach { mom in
    print(mom.name)
}
```

If I put this in a workspace, everything is good until I hit the run button. At which point it tells me that the last expression `Mom.all()` is ambiguous. Why is this? Is there not a way to have a class func which refines in the subclass for the subtype, and keep them unambiguous?

Comment: Name a method as a verb phrase (`getAll`) and a property as a noun to avoid the weird casing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that the `all` on `Parent` and the `all` on `Mom` have different signatures. Thus, the `all` on `Mom` cannot be an override for that on `Parent` (also shown by the fact that the compiler does not require the `override` keyword). What this means is that two class functions named `all` exist on the `Mom` type. Furthermore, the closure you are passing to `forEach` does not specify a parameter type, so it is impossible to be sure of which of the two functions is being referenced. Assigning a type to the `mom` parameter in the `forEach` will solve this problem.

Comment: Yep, makes sense now. Once I change `mom in` to `(mom:Mom)`, all is well.

Answer (score -2):

Until you instantiate a Mom, and call it on that instance of Mom, it will be ambiguous.